# Redis Transaction Error

Tags: node.js, redis

I am Getting this error :-

ReplyError: EXECABORT Transaction discarded because of previous errors.

at parseError (/home/ubuntu/code/ams-api/node_modules/redis-
parser/lib/parser.js:193:12)

at parseType (/home/ubuntu/code/ams-api/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:303:14)

What I am Using is

1. Redis **[RSMQ](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsmq)**
2. Redis **[Worker](https://github.com/mpneuried/rsmq-worker)**

Is their any way to solve this Error without changing npm modules

Any Help will be appreciated ..